# Example of a linear operator pointwise bounded but not uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis

I was going through the uniform boundedness principle and I need a motivation of a sequence of operator which is Pointwise bounded but not Uniformly. Can anybody help me? Any suggestion is appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: The uniform boundedness principle is about _families_ of linear maps. On certain spaces, every pointwise bounded family of linear maps is uniformly bounded. Are you looking for a pointwise bounded family that is not uniformly bounded (on a space of a different kind, necessarily)?

Comment: Please clarify your definitions.  It's not clear to me what it means for a single operator to be pointwise or uniformly bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer : exactly. I am seeking fora family of linear operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the uniform boundedness principle, the domain of such a family cannot be a Banach space. A fruitful source for "counterexamples" to things that are true in Banach spaces are the

$$\ell^p_{00} = \left\{ x\in \ell^p : \operatorname{card} \{k\in\mathbb{N} : x_k \neq 0 \} < \infty\right\}$$

spaces of sequences with finite support in the various $\ell^p$-norms.

Let us take $\ell^1_{00}$, and let

$$\Lambda_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot x_k.$$

Then $\{ \Lambda_n(x) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a finite set for each $x\in \ell^1_{00}$, thus the family is pointwise bounded, but the family is easily seen to be not uniformly bounded, since $\lVert\Lambda_n\rVert = n$.

Comment: Excuse me can u explain in short why $||T_n||$=$n$ ?

Comment: If we take the $n$-th "standard basis" vector, we have $\Lambda_n(e^{n}) = \sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot e^{n}_k = n$, and generally $$\lvert \Lambda_n(x)\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^n k\lvert x_k\rvert \leqslant n\sum_{k=0}^n \lvert x_k\rvert \leqslant n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lvert x_k\rvert = n\cdot \lVert x\rVert_{\ell^1}.$$ The first shows $\lVert\Lambda\rVert \geqslant n$, the second shows $\leqslant n$.

Comment: So $\ell^1_{00}$ is not a Banach space. Right? In fact it indicates $\ell^1_{00}$ is not closed subspace of $\ell^1$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Right. $\ell^p_{00}$ is a dense proper subspace of $\ell^p$ for $1 \leqslant p < \infty$. (The closure in $\ell^{\infty}$ is $c_0$, the subspace of sequences converging to $0$.)